# Bitcoin sending transaction error

Tags: transactions, error

I recently bought some Bitcoins(around 0.5) and sent some to a friend. He got them direct. Today I wanted to transfer some more but it didn't work. Every transaction was an error, besides one very small one(0.001 BTC).
All transactions are marked with a questionmark, so they are not confirmed for whatever reason.
After I restarted my bitcoin client, most of the transactions were marked with an exclamation mark.
I have no idea why I can not send money any more. Anyone having similiar problems and got a solution?

Thank you!

Here is a screenshot btw: [image]

Comment: There could be many reasons for this. Provide us with the transaction numbers for better assistance. It could be related to transaction fees being too low, unconfirmed inputs or something else.

Comment: Alright here is the complete CFG:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hrAl7Okyv3bGRrV1RyYUVNMDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: BTW: The Transactions from Luca were chargedback aswell... : (